# How to feed BertMasked language model a synthetic input embedding

Tags: bert-language-model

I'm trying to find a way to average out embeddings of target word and its synonyms to find semantically and contextually close candidates of the target word by using the BERT model.

I can't seem to find a way to somehow synthesize the embeddings and feed the BERT to get "good" candidates for paraphrase. Can someone explain a way by the code?